# How to plot the derivative after indicating the value?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, finite-element-method

I have used the FEM tool to solve this PDE system with control equation and boundary conditions, after calculation the `ufun1[x, y]` are calculated, and I want the partial derivative of the `ufun1[x, y]` and plot the curve of `D[ufun1[x, y], y]] /. {y -> 0.15}` and `-D[ufun1[x, y], x]] /. {y -> 0.15}`.

**As the above results are all the 2D function of `x` and `y`, so and I indicate that `{y -> 0.15}` and then we can plot one curve vs. `x`, however, I can not plot the second one, what is the reason?**

The codes are as follows:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
(*sh=0.2;sh2=0.02;sw=0.3;*)
ToothNumber = 3;
SlotNumber = ToothNumber - 1;
RectangleNumber = ToothNumber + SlotNumber;

ToothLength = 0.1;

ToothHeight = 0.1;
SlotHeight = 0.1;

coordinates = {{0., 0.}, {ToothLength, 0}, {ToothLength, 
    ToothHeight}, {2*ToothLength, ToothHeight}, {2*ToothLength, 
    0}, {3*ToothLength, 0}, {3*ToothLength, 
    ToothHeight}, {4*ToothLength, ToothHeight}, {4*ToothLength, 
    0}, {5*ToothLength, 0}, {5*ToothLength, 
    ToothHeight + SlotHeight}, {0, ToothHeight + SlotHeight}};
el1 = LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7,
      8}, {8, 9}, {9, 10}, {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {12, 1}}];
bMesh2 = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {el1}];
GraphicsRow[{bMesh2["Wireframe"]}]

mesh2 = ToElementMesh[bMesh2];
mesh2["Wireframe"]

\[Mu]Air = 4 \[Pi]*10^-7;
Km = 10^5;
m = 1;
p = 2;
alpha = 0;

K[x_] := Km*Cos[m*p*(x - alpha)];


(*it is one matrix*)
op1 = Inactive[Div][(*-\[Epsilon]r.*)
    Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] - 
   NeumannValue[0, 
    x == ToothLength || x == 2*ToothLength || x == 3*ToothLength || 
     x == 4*ToothLength || y == ToothHeight || y == 0(*||
    x\[LessEqual]sw&&sh\[LessEqual]y\[LessEqual]sh+sh2*)];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 
  D] = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == \[Mu]Air*K[x], 
    0 <= x <= 5*ToothLength && y == ToothHeight + SlotHeight], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == 0 || x == 5*ToothLength]};

ufun1 = NDSolveValue[{op1 == 0, Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D]}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh2];

(*
Bx[x_,y_]:=D[ufun1,y];
By[x_,y_]:=-D[ufun1,x];
*)
{minsol, maxsol} = MinMax[ufun1["ValuesOnGrid"]]
(*
ufun2=NDSolveValue[{op2\[Equal]0,Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], \
D]},u,{x,y}\[Element]mesh2];
*)
Show[ContourPlot[ufun1[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh2, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  Contours -> Range[minsol, maxsol, (maxsol - minsol)/50], 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic],
 bMesh2["Wireframe"]]


Plot[Evaluate[D[ufun1[x, y], y]] /. {y -> 0.15}, {x, 0, 0.5}]

Plot[Evaluate[-D[ufun1[x, y], x]] /. {y -> 0.15}, {x, 0, 0.5}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a conflict between the `plot variable x` and the `derivative  variable x`!

Try for the last plot

```
Plot[ -Derivative[1, 0][ufun1][x, .15]  , {x, 0, 0.5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, great answer! And what do you mean of the conflict?

Comment: Other workarounds are `Plot[Evaluate[-D [ufun1[xx, .15], xx] /. xx -> x], {x, 0, 0.5}]` or `deriv = D [ufun1[x , .15], x ];Plot[ -deriv , {x, 0, 0.5}]`.
`